# 'TypeError: Object is not a function' when using tunnel-ssh

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, npm, tunnel

I'm running the basic example in the tutorial for the popular NPM package [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh). Here is the code:

```
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');
var config = {
    username:'root',
    password:'secret',
    host:'remote.mysql.server.com',
    port:3306
}

tunnel(config, function(e, sshTunnel){
    //Now, you should be able to connect to the tunnel via localhost:3336.
});
```

I am running it with the credentials for my own database of course. However, I always get this error when I run it:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: You're not doing anything at all inside the tunnel callback?

Comment: @Paul I've tried running it with a simple console.log statement inside the callback. Still get the error.

Comment: have  you tried doing it from the cli w/o using the package?  i.e. ssh root@remote.mysql.server.com -L 3306:localhost:3306?  Might be that the remote side is rejecting the connection due to wrong credentials or something (like, if you're trying to login with the mysql credentials, and the ssh user has different creds, or the mysql user isn't ssh enabled)

Comment: @Paul I just tried running that command and I was able to get into the database, so it looks like it isn't a problem with the remote side rejecting the connection. :/ It must be a problem with the npm package?

Comment: what line is the error on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');

var config = {username: 'vagrant',host: '192.168.33.2', port:3307, dstPort:3306 }

tunnel.tunnel(config, function(e, sshTunnel){});
```

I have my key added in 192.168.33.2 and forwarding the destination port 3306 to my local port 3307.

I am running this on RPEL node version v0.12.4. Its working.

Comment: Still no luck. I defined the dstPort, dstHost, privateKey... but still get the same compile error.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the error! Just wanted to point out, however, that I had to modify dstPort to be the default MongoDB port (dstPort: '27017'), as specified in the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh. Kinda funky but hey, it works.

Comment: Which means you are forwarding MongoDB, standard port 27017 to the 'port' you have defined.